# ui updating to move background

Tags: java, android

Can I do something like below to update UI. I actually want to move background image or a bitmap like animation.If not please help me with correction.I am new in Android.

```
float x=0;
float y=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);

    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {

                    for(;x<=200;)
                    {
                        x++;
                        img.setX(x);


                        try
                        {
                            sleep(1000);

                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Exception: "+e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

}.start();

}
```

Comment: having a thread here is pretty useless since you run everything on the UI thread anyway

Comment: non-UI thread cannot modify UI, you have to use handler

Comment: I don't know how to use handler.Can you please give an example of that. @mangusta